# VK Api - First steps

Tags: php, api, vk

i'm trying to work with VK Api. I see methods for getting user ID.

```
method=getProfiles&uids={viewer_id}&format=json&v=2.0
```

Can you please show an example of using it? An example sending query to VK Api, and getting result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=205387401&fields=photo_50,city,verified
Check new API link for VK: http://vk.com/dev/users
I think it can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use info from vk.com/dev

I use JavaScript and jQuery for work.

```js
function sendRequest(method, params, func) {
    $.ajax({
    url: getUrl(method, params),
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success: func
    }); 
}
```